# How do I insert cells in a table view after (not before) an API call is done?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I'm working on a weather app. I update the simple `UILabel`s no problem but the issue is populating a `TableView` with the weather data I will get from the API. In my `ViewController` I have `var weatherModel: WeatherModel?` structure which will get set after I parse JSON data into it. When the user first launches the app I get his current location with `CLLocationManager.requestLocation()` triggered from `viewDidLoad()` then I perform a call to weather API inside 
 `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`. Then I update the UI. But of course the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` will get triggered long before my API call is complete so when I try to unwrap my `weatherModel` inside I get `nil`. I set the `tableView.datasource` and `delegate` inside the `viewDidLoad()`. I tried requesting the location before setting the `tableView.dataSource` like so but that doesn't work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    searchField.delegate = self
    weatherController.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestLocation()
    DataTable.delegate = self
    DataTable.dataSource = self
    DataTable.register(UINib(nibName: "DataCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DataCell")
}
```

Maybe I should request for the location in `viewWillAppear()` so that the API call is done before the `tableView cellForRowAt` gets triggered?

Comment: you can call table.reloadData() after API call. but if you want to setup UI hold for API call, you can add UI setup parts to one function and call it after API success.

Comment: This code is not related to the problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an empty array like `var weatherInfoArray:[WeatherModel] = []`, so when the tableview initialized, the `numberOfItemsInSection`is 0 and you don't need to worry about `cellForRowAt`.
And This would be better if you don't really know whether a variable is nil or not:`if let weatherModel = weatherModel {...}` so if the weatherModel is nil, the code will never be executed.